# Oracle Structure for loop column of table

Tags: oracle, plsql

At work, they developed a code, where they declare one table with a %ROWTYPE (that table have 243 columns), and for every column they inserted a value.

MYTABLE

```
COL_001 VARCHAR2(4000)
COL_002 VARCHAR2(4000)
..
COL_243 VARCHAR2(4000)
```

as you can see they are all VARCHAR2. this table was created because the data are readed from a csv file and then are inserted on that table.

code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEUDRE AS TEST
v_rec MYTABLE%ROW_TYPE;

BEGIN
  v_rec.COL001 := value;
  v_rec.COL002 := value;
  ...
  v_rec.COL243 := value;
END TEST;
```

is it possible with other data structures to create a loop?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEUDRE AS TEST
v_rec MYTABLE%ROW_TYPE;

BEGIN
  for i in 1..243 loop
     v_rec.i:= value;
  end loop;
END TEST;
```

Comment: *"this table was created because the data are readed from a csv file and then are inserted on that table."* In other words, this table was created because nobody wanted to use Oracle's built-in capabilities such as SQL\*Loader or external tables.

Answer (score 1):

to loop thru the columns you may use dbms_sql utility
Here is an Example

```
DROP TABLE ABC;
CREATE TABLE ABC (COL1, COL2, COL243) AS
SELECT '1001', 'LO SABIA', 'I KNEW IT' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '1002', 'NO IMPORTA','IT DOES NOT MATTER' FROM DUAL;
/
DECLARE
   --
   l_query            VARCHAR2(4000) := 'Select * from abc';-------------replace table name to test
   l_thecursor        INTEGER DEFAULT dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   l_columnvalue      VARCHAR2(4000);
   l_status           INTEGER;
   l_colcnt           NUMBER := 0;
   l_separator        VARCHAR2(1) := '|';
   l_desctbl          dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   l_insert_col_list  VARCHAR2(3000);
   l_insert_row_line  VARCHAR2(3000);
   l_insert_data_line VARCHAR2(3000);
   TYPE numberstab IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   l_col_pad numberstab; --column size
   --
BEGIN
   dbms_sql.parse(l_thecursor, l_query, dbms_sql.native);
   l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_thecursor);
   --
   --describe columns
   dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_thecursor, l_colcnt, l_desctbl);
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_colcnt
   LOOP
      l_col_pad(i) := greatest(l_desctbl(i).col_name_len,
                               CASE l_desctbl(i).col_type
                                   WHEN 12 --date
                                    THEN
                                    10
                                   WHEN 2 THEN --number
                                    6
                                   ELSE
                                    greatest(l_desctbl(i).col_max_len, 4)
                                END);
      l_insert_col_list := l_insert_col_list || l_separator ||
                           lpad(l_desctbl(i).col_name, l_col_pad(i), ' ');
      l_insert_row_line := l_insert_row_line || '+' || lpad('-', l_col_pad(i), '-');
      dbms_sql.define_column(l_thecursor, i, l_columnvalue, 4000);
   END LOOP;
   --
   l_insert_row_line := l_insert_row_line || '+';
   dbms_output.put_line(l_insert_row_line);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_insert_col_list || '|');
   dbms_output.put_line(l_insert_row_line);
   --
   --ROWS
   WHILE (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_thecursor)) > 0
   LOOP
      --COLUMNS
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_colcnt
      LOOP            
         dbms_sql.column_value(l_thecursor, i, l_columnvalue);--retrieve column value
         --replace this section with the code you need 
         IF l_columnvalue IS NULL
         THEN
            l_insert_data_line := l_insert_data_line || l_separator ||
                                  lpad('Null', l_col_pad(i), ' ');
         ELSIF l_desctbl(i).col_type IN (12)
         THEN
            l_insert_data_line := l_insert_data_line || l_separator ||
                                  lpad(to_char(to_date(l_columnvalue, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                                       l_col_pad(i), ' ');
         ELSE
            l_insert_data_line := l_insert_data_line || l_separator ||
                                  lpad(l_columnvalue, l_col_pad(i), ' ');
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_insert_data_line || '|');
      l_insert_data_line := '';
      --
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line(l_insert_row_line);
   dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_thecursor);
END;
```

this will produce the following output

```
+----+----------+------------------+
|COL1|      COL2|            COL243|
+----+----------+------------------+
|1001|  LO SABIA|         I KNEW IT|
|1002|NO IMPORTA|IT DOES NOT MATTER|
+----+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach:
Step 1 - Extract the column names to a string from meta data.Convert rows to columns using XMLAGG.

```
select
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, column_name || ',') order by column_name).extract ('//text()'),',') 
into lv_columns from
  (select table_name,column_name from  user_Tab_columns where table_name ='TESTTAB'
  order by column_name asc) tab
group by
   table_name;
```

Step 2 - Generate sequential numbers based on number of columns using CONNECT BY LEVEL. Convert the resulting rows to columns using XMLAGG again and extract it to a string.Change the number for 4 to 243 as desired.

```
select
  rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, level || ',')).extract ('//text()'),',') 
into lv_values FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level < 4
;
```

Step 3 - Formulate query for insertion for the columns from step 1 with values extracted from step 2.

```
lv_query := 'insert into TESTTAB ('||lv_columns||') values ('||lv_values||')';
```

Step 4 - Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to execute the insert query.

```
execute immediate lv_query;
```

For complete solution refer the DBFIDDLE link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edcc497332e87c50273369440646e402

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the question - you'd use *collections*.

Sample table; I didn't feel like creating a table with 200 columns so - 3 will do.

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL_001                                  COL_002        COL_003
---------------------------------------- -------------- -------------
10                                       ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
20                                       RESEARCH       DALLAS
30                                       SALES          CHICAGO
40                                       OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

PL/SQL code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    -- this is were you'll store contents of the table
  3    type testtype is table of test%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  4    test_tab testtype;
  5  begin
  6    -- fetch table contents into TEST_TAB
  7    select *
  8      bulk collect into test_tab
  9      from test;
 10
 11    -- you'd do something with it; I'm just displaying some values
 12    for i in test_tab.first .. test_tab.last loop
 13      dbms_output.put_line(test_tab(i).col_001 ||' '|| test_tab(i).col_002);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
10 ACCOUNTING
20 RESEARCH
30 SALES
40 OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you were asking?

```
create or replace package test_pkg as

   v_rec mytable%rowtype;

   procedure proc;

end test_pkg;
/

create or replace package body test_pkg as

   procedure proc is
   begin

      for i in 1 .. 243 loop
         execute immediate 'begin
                               test_pkg.v_rec.col_' || lpad(i, 3, '0') || ' := :x;
                            end;'
           using value;
      end loop;

   end proc;

end test_pkg;
/
```