# Dynamic variable names in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wonder if it possible in oracle to create dynamic variable name. The code is simplified. I just wanna show what I mean.

The table is defined as

```
create or replace TYPE         "rep_table_T" AS TABLE OF rep_table_O;
```

The object is defined as:

```
create or replace TYPE         "rep_table_O" AS OBJECT (       
    day1 VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    ....
    day31 VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),

    TS DATE
    );
```

I wanna do some computation and save the results in fields with variable names:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE MY_HELPER (myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T) IS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEGIN   

    FOR nCOUNT IN 1..31
    LOOP
        IF NVL(rep_table (nIndex-2).day||nCOUNT , 0) > 0 THEN
            rep_table (nIndex).day||nCOUNT  := ROUND((1 - rep_table (nIndex-1).day||nCOUNT  / rep_table (nIndex-2).day||nCOUNT ) * 100, 2);--here I wanna  have variables day1 .. to day31
        END IF; 
    END LOOP;
END MY_HELPER;
```

Instead of writhing it like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE MY_HELPER (myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T) IS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEGIN   

    IF NVL(rep_table (nIndex-2).day1 , 0) > 0 THEN
            rep_table (nIndex).day1  := ROUND((1 - rep_table (nIndex-1).TAG1  / rep_table (nIndex-2).day1 ) * 100, 2);
    END IF; 
    ......
    IF NVL(rep_table (nIndex-2).day31 , 0) > 0 THEN
                rep_table (nIndex).day31  := ROUND((1 - rep_table (nIndex-1).day1  / rep_table (nIndex-2).day31 ) * 100, 2);
    END IF; 
END MY_HELPER;
```

Any clue?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with dynamic variables?  In this example, it would seem to make vastly more sense to have a collection with 31 elements in it.  But I don't know whether you've simplified the actual problem out of your code-- perhaps you really want to use dynamic PL/SQL for some reason.

Comment: you  can use table of int (table type) to store the data if its what you want

Comment: I have a virtual table- It has colum names day1 to 31. I wish to make some computation in a loop instead of writing 
`my_table(my_idx).day1: = 0;` 31 times I wish to do it once.

Comment: @hajduk - I'm guessing from your syntax that when you say "virtual table" you mean that you have a collection of objects or records and those objects have fields called `day1` through `day31`.  If that you want to run operations on each day in a loop, that implies that you'd actually want your data structure to have fields called, say, `day_num` and `value` and that you have 31 of them rather than having separate fields.

Comment: @Justin Cave Yes, you are right.

Comment: PL/SQL is static, its variables need to be declared with specific datatype (although, it allows implicit conversions). PL/SQL units are compiled and then executed. But if you have a lot of input objects with different structure, then you either already coded it in static way (then you can also code their structure again) or may use another interface structure for generalized processing. As long as you didn't provide more details about your problem, it is hard to tell what to do.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what information I can provide. I just wonder if it possible to loop  through `rep_table(myIdx).day1`.. `rep_table(myIdx).day31` dynamically instead of write it 31 times.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718685/oracle-structure-for-loop-column-of-table/64731039#64731039

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you want to achieve with the computations you were mentioning, I think you could use something like this ( it is just an example very basic for you to get the idea )

```
 set serveroutput on size unlimited
    declare
      x pls_integer;
      function get_me_val ( pday in pls_integer
      ) return number
      is
      begin
        if pday = 1 
        then 
            return 1 ;
        else
            return pday-1; 
        end if; 
      end get_me_val;
    begin
    for i in 1..31
    loop
        x := get_me_val(pday => i);
        dbms_output.put_line(x);
    end loop;
    end;
    /
```

Basically you transfer the logic of the loop to the function, then you don't need to write anything 30 times inside a loop. Of course, it depends entirely of what kind of calculations you want to do with the values.

The advantage of this solution is that you can use anything for the the function, not only a normal `for-loop` , but also any kind of loop construction over collections or arrays.

```
SQL> declare
  x pls_integer;
  function get_me_val ( pday in pls_integer
  ) return number
  is
  begin
        if pday = 1
        then
                return 1 ;
        else
                return pday-1;
        end if;
  end get_me_val;
begin
for i in 1..31
loop
        x := get_me_val(pday => i);
        dbms_output.put_line(x);
end loop;
end;
/ 
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Update**

Honestly, it is quite difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. Anyway, here a silly example on how to apply logic inside a function using a collection, then iterated through the values without repeating anything. As I told you before, the trick is to extract the logic from the loop and use a function for it.

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
  type days_of_month is table of number;
  dys days_of_month;
  x pls_integer;
  function get_me_val ( pday in pls_integer ) return number
  is
  y pls_integer;
  n pls_integer;
  begin
     if pday > 2 
     then
         n := round(dbms_random.value(2,4),0);
         y := round( (1-(pday-1)*n) / (pday-2)*n*100 ,0);
     else
         y := 1 ;
     end if;
  return y;  
  end get_me_val;
begin
dys := days_of_month(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
for i in dys.first .. dys.last
loop
    x := get_me_val(pday => dys(i));
    dbms_output.put_line(x);
end loop;
end;
/
```

If I run it

```
SQL> declare
  2    type days_of_month is table of number;
  3    dys days_of_month;
  4    x pls_integer;
  5    function get_me_val ( pday in pls_integer ) return number
  6    is
  7    y pls_integer;
  8    n pls_integer;
  9    begin
 10      if pday > 2
 11      then
 12              n := round(dbms_random.value(2,4),0);
 13           y := round( (1-(pday-1)*n) / (pday-2)*n*100 ,0);
 14       else
 15              y := 1 ;
 16      end if;
 17    return y;
 18    end get_me_val;
 19  begin
 20  dys := days_of_month(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
 21  for i in dys.first .. dys.last
 22  loop
 23     x := get_me_val(pday => dys(i));
 24     dbms_output.put_line(x);
 25  end loop;
 26* end;
SQL> /
1
1
-1500
-2200
-467
-450
-1020
-1000
-986
-1750
-967
-960
-1709
-1700
-415
-943
-940
-1675
-935
-933
-932
-1660
-410
-927
-926
-1650
-408
-923
-922
-1643

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I also wish to save the result in my virtual table. In fields  `my_table(my_idx).day1: = 0;` .. `my_table(my_idx).day31: = 0;`

Comment: can you put the code you have for this collection and what exactly do you want to do with it ? You can operate with the collection inside the function, but I have no idea what kind of collection or array or nested table are you using, so I can't say

Comment: Ok, I did edit now.

Comment: Again, you are not explaining what are you doing with the 31 days. Assign them all to a variable with 0 ? For what exactly ? sorry, but it does not make any sense

Comment: I did edit. However even 0 makes sense(for example initialization) although it was wirtiiten to simplfy the code.

Comment: I need to store the values in `rep_table (nIndex).day1` `rep_table (nIndex).day31`. I ask if I can do it in the loop instead of writing a long code.